# Loop through entries within a category loop but only show once?

Tags: twig, craftcms

In a CraftCMs site I'm trying to loop through a couple categories, then loop through entries within each of those categories, but without duplicating the entry if it is in both categories.
Here's my base code:

```
{% set selectedCategories = craft.categories()
  .id([12605, 12619])
  .all()
%}

{% set articleAuthor = entry.id %}

  {% for category in selectedCategories %}

      {% set articles = craft.entries()
        .section('articles')
        .relatedTo([
          'and', {articleAuthor}, {category}])
        .all() %}

    {% if articles %}

      {% for article in articles %}

      // entry data here

      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

This works, but if an entry is in both categories it shows in both sections. I want to limit it to showing in whatever may be the first listed section. What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you just prepare your (unique) data in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you can create a variable and check whether a duplicate entry is found or not.

```
{% set existingIds = [] %}
{% for article in articles %}
    {% if entry.id not in existingIds %}
        {% set existingIds = existingIds|merge([entry.id]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```